# Count the number of transaction based on day in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table which maintain the transaction history for various study, want to fetch the study group by study id (which is `TIM`) for last week, last month and last 6 month

```
SELECT CREATED_DATE,TIMS,COUNT(TIMS) FROM STUDY_HISTORY
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= DATE'2023-03-06'
GROUP BY CREATED_DATE,TIMS
ORDER BY CREATED_DATE
```

Above query is not adding up properly and also dont know how to retrieve it for last month and 6 month.

[image]

Comment: **Hint** : `systimestamp - interval '6' month`

Comment: Do you mean, what I can observe from the image that it should show, e.g. 247012 should show 2 for 06-03-2023 and hence forth ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query can't work; if you're grouping by date column, you get ... well, what you got. Try conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  sum(case when created_date >= add_months(sysdate, -6) then 1 else 0 end) last_6_months,
  sum(case when created_date >= add_months(sysdate, -1) then 1 else 0 end) last_month,
  sum(case when created_date >= sysdate - 7             then 1 else 0 end) last_week
from study_history
```

Comment: Thank you this should be included in my query ?

Comment: No, this *is* your "new" query.